# Customise my jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to change the background colour when I click a link on my Accordion.

I assume this means adding/removing an 'active' class on clicking the element.

Can someone explain how I do this with my code?

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2hmzcgqm/5/)

```
(function($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        if ($(this).parent().next().is(":visible")) return false;
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        return false;
    });
    $('.accordion > dt > a').first().trigger('click');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: the background-color of your hyperlink or... ?

Comment: Apologies. The `background-color` of `.heading` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2hmzcgqm/6/

**JS code:**

```
(function($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    var allLinks = $('a.heading');
    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
        allPanels.slideUp();

        //Remove all 
        allLinks.removeClass('active');

        if ($(this).parent().next().is(":visible")) return false;
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();

        //Add active class
        $(this).addClass('active');

        return false;
    });
    $('.accordion > dt > a').first().trigger('click');
})(jQuery);
```

**CSS code:**

```
.heading {background:red}
.active {background:black}
```

Comment: Absolutely stellar, VDesign!! Many thanks for including comments too - this will help educate me for the future :-)

Comment: no problem, if you have further questions please ask